# How to list processes communicating with the Internet

Tags: networking, bash, netstat

I'm trying to detect if my target processes are communicating with the Internet.

Here is what I edit my script named test.sh:

```
a=$(pgrep -f $1)
a=$(echo $a | sed -e 's/ /\\|/g')
a="'${a}'"
cmd="netstat -p | grep $a"
eval $cmd
```

Now I can execute it:
`./test.sh ros`

Now I can see all of the net situation of the processes about `ros`.

However, it lists all cases, including all of the IPC (inter-process communication), which I don't need.

Is there a way to exclude all of the IPCs?

Comment: [`man netstat`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/netstat.8.html); in particular, you may find `netstat -tu` useful. You may also want to consider [`ss`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/ss.8.html).

Comment: @AlexP  Are you sure about `-tu`? I think IPC may use tcp or udp too.